# PyQt5 GroupBox Layouts Feedback

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I will import given code for my main `QMainWindow`.(I only add import sys etc. to run it)
Is there a more compact way to code this lines.
Output is correct for my expectation.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class ButtonWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ButtonWidget, self).__init__()

        # Function
        button1 = QRadioButton("Sinus")
        button2 = QRadioButton("Cosines")
        # Color
        button3 = QRadioButton("Red")
        button4 = QRadioButton("Green")
        # Line
        button5 = QRadioButton("Solid")
        button6 = QRadioButton("Dashed")
        # Left Group
        left_group = QGroupBox("Left Group")
        left_group_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        left_group_layout.addWidget(button1)
        left_group_layout.addWidget(button2)
        left_group.setLayout(left_group_layout)
        # Middle Group
        middle_group = QGroupBox("Middle Group")
        middle_group_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        middle_group_layout.addWidget(button3)
        middle_group_layout.addWidget(button4)
        middle_group.setLayout(middle_group_layout)
        # Right Group
        right_group = QGroupBox("Right Group")
        right_group_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        right_group_layout.addWidget(button5)
        right_group_layout.addWidget(button6)
        right_group.setLayout(right_group_layout)
        # Main Group
        main_group = QGroupBox("Main Group")
        main_group_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        main_group_layout.addWidget(left_group)
        main_group_layout.addWidget(middle_group)
        main_group_layout.addWidget(right_group)
        main_group.setLayout(main_group_layout)
        # Widget
        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_widget_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_widget.setLayout(main_widget_layout)
        main_widget_layout.addWidget(main_group)
        # Layout Set
        self.setLayout(main_widget_layout)

        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = ButtonWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a solution. The obvious solution is of course to use loops.
Here is my try using a composite dictionary. It is functionally equivalent to your code and will save you about a dozen lines but hopefully adds flexibility. This was a quick job, so maybe you can take it further.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class ButtonWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ButtonWidget, self).__init__()

        groups = {"Left Group": ("Sinus", "Cosines"),
            "Middle Group": ("Red", "Green"),
            "Right Group": ("Solid", "Dashed")
        }

        # Main Group
        main_group = QGroupBox("Main Group")
        main_group_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        # loop on group names
        for group, buttons in groups.items():
            group_box = QGroupBox(group)
            group_layout = QVBoxLayout()
            for button_text in buttons:
                group_layout.addWidget(QRadioButton(button_text))

            group_box.setLayout(group_layout)
            main_group_layout.addWidget(group_box)

        main_group.setLayout(main_group_layout)

        # Widget
        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_widget_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_widget.setLayout(main_widget_layout)
        main_widget_layout.addWidget(main_group)
        # Layout Set
        self.setLayout(main_widget_layout)

        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = ButtonWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

NB: you'll probably have to add names to the generated controls (the buttons at least).

PS: personally I use the QT designer to build forms unless I need a highly dynamic layout. Adding controls in code is tedious and less visual.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to create engineering calculation GUI for my job. I think, I can create basic one. However I also want to improve myself. I will use numpy etc. What do you suggest for not highly dynamic layout